# uploadify what port ? on amazon ec2 issues

Tags: amazon-ec2, uploadify

I am using uploadify on my server which is hosted on amazon ec2, i have port 80 and 22 open, which port does Uploadify use so i can fix it?

The problem is that uploadify make the customer believe that the image is uploaded but i doesn't arrive on my server, i think it is the port since it worked on my old server with hostgator

my code on the form is:

```
// <![CDATA[



$(document).ready(function() {

$("#dialog").dialog({

        bgiframe: true,

        height: 250,

        width:400,

        autoOpen: false,

        modal: false,

        buttons: {

            'cancel order': function() {

                $(this).dialog('close');

                $('#file_upload').uploadifyClearQueue();

                $('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel(($('.uploadifyQueueItem').first().attr('id').replace('file_upload','')));



            },

            'confirm order': function() {

                 $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();

                 $(this).dialog('close');

            }

        }

});



$('#file_upload').uploadify({

'uploader'  : 'swf/uploadify.swf',

'script'    : 'swf/uploadify.php?userid=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>',

'cancelImg' : 'image/cancel.png',

'folder'    : 'uploads',

'buttonImg' : 'image/uploadbtn.png',

'height'    : 120,

'width'     : 400,

'sizeLimit' : 299240000,

'auto'      : false,

'queueSizeLimit' : 3,

'scriptData': {'session_name': '<?php echo session_id(); ?>'},

'checkScript' : 'ajaxfiles/check.php',

'onSelect'    : function(event,ID,fileObj) {

  $('#dialog').dialog('open');

  var price=$('#templateprice').val();

  var txt="You are now uploading 1 image at a price of $ "+price+" pr. image ";

  $('#test_para').text(txt);

},

'onError'     : function (event,ID,fileObj,errorObj) {

  alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);

},

'onProgress'  : function(event,ID,fileObj,data) {

  var bytes = Math.round(data.bytesLoaded / 1024);

  $('#' + $(event.target).attr('id') + ID).find('.percentage').text(' - ' + bytes + 'KB Uploaded');

  return false;

},

'onAllComplete'  : function(){ alert("Thank you. File uploaded successfully."); }

});

});



// ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify uses http or https to upload files to a PHP script.

If you have both ports 80 and 22 open, the issue must lie elsewhere.

I suggest you investigate file permissions on the server

> Make sure the permissions of your upload folder are correct.  If you’re unsure or what permissions to set them to, use 755.

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/making-uploadify-secure/

Comment: i allow: 21 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
25 (SMTP) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
3389 (RDP) 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Did you check permissions of your upload folder?  Your ports look fine.